# Why chrome not loading new page, However I try?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, page-refresh

Any one know how can I refresh a page when its not loading the newer version of it from ther server.

I have tried F5 repeatedly, Ctrl + F5 and cleared browsing data.

Is there any other posiblities...

Are there any server issues which should be tweak if such problem persist ?

Comment: What's the URL, is it publicly accessible? Is there anything showing in developer tools under the network tab?

Answer (score 3):

If you clear browser cache and DNS cache, you should see the new version of the page. If you think it's not the new version of the page, most probably you've not changed it on the server!

You can also use sites like http://snapito.com to check the visual appearance of your site from a browser different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you clear the browser cache, then you are sure to have a brand new version displayed in the browser.

Check if you did change anything **on the server**. Maybe you didn't upload changes?